# Disabling "Deferred Revenue" on an existing system: bad idea?

Tags: civicontribute, bookkeeping

If a CiviCRM installation has been running with Deferred Revenue long enough to have many transactions affected by that configuration, what are the negative impacts of disabling it now?

I'm thinking this would result in some kind of inconsistent state, as there will be new contributions not handled under Deferred Revenue, at the same time there will be various deferred transactions still being "worked down" (e.g., events with future dates, membership values being parceled out over time, etc.). Is this true, and is it problematic?

If there's documentation somewhere explaining why this is not recommended, that would be a useful source.